# How to display only child categories and products in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to display only child categories and products in WooCommerce?

There is such a code example:
`

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';
$orderby = 'name';
$order = 'ASC';
$show_count = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts = 0; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1; // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$title = '';
$empty = 1;

$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order,  
    'show_count' => $show_count,
    'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
    'title_li' => $title,
    'hide_empty' => $empty,
    'parent' => 0
);

$all_categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    $category_id = $cat->term_id;
    $args2 = array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy,'parent' => $category_id,'hierarchical' => $hierarchical, 'orderby' => $orderby, 'order' => $order,'hide_empty' => $empty);
$categories = get_categories( $args2 );
$categories_cnt = count(get_categories( $args2 ));


if ($categories_cnt != 0){
echo "<ul class='category'><li>".$cat->name;
$sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
            if($sub_cats) {
echo "<ul>";
                foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                    echo "<li>".$sub_category->cat_name;

                    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product','product_cat' => $sub_category->slug, 'orderby' => $orderby, 'order' => $order);
                            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                            echo "<ul class='products'>";
                                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?> <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">
                                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                                    </a></li>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </ul>
                            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

                    <?php echo "</li>";

                    }
echo "</ul></ul>";
}
}
else {
    echo "<ul class='category'><li>".$cat->name;
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'product_cat' => $cat->slug, 'orderby' => $orderby, 'order' => $order );
                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                    echo "<ul class='products'>";
                        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?> <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </a></li>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </ul></li></ul>
                    <?php wp_reset_query();
    echo "</li></ul>";

}

}
?>
```

`
It displays a list of categories and products under each category (if there are products).
I need to make sure that only child categories are displayed, and not all that are on the site.

I really ask for help, I've been suffering with this for the second day:(

P.S. There is another example that outputs a list of child categories. It works as it should, but does not display products under categories.
`

```
<?php
      if ( is_product_category() ) {
        $term = get_queried_object();
        $taxonomy = $term->taxonomy;
      
        echo '<h3>Запчасти для ' . $term->name . '<h3>'; // выводим текущую категорию
        echo '<div class="subcategories-woc">';
        // получаем дочерние, если существуют
        if ( $term_children = get_term_children( $term->term_id, $taxonomy ) ) {
          echo '<ul>';
          foreach ( $term_children as $key => $term_child ) {
            $term_child = get_term_by( 'id', $term_child, $taxonomy );
            // выводим дочерние
      if ( $term->term_id == $term_child->parent ) {
        echo '<li class="shadow"><a href="' . get_term_link( $term_child->term_id, $taxonomy ) . '">' . $term_child->name . '</a></li>';
      }
      
          }
          echo '</ul>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Top-level categories should have the `parent` property set to `0`, so you should be able to simply skip those in your loop.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please show an example?

Comment: `if (!$cat->parent) { continue; }` at the beginning of the loop should probably do the trick.